Why can <image> inside <svg> be :focus'ed?
I have an <image> element within an <svg> element, embedded into HTML markup. Somehow the <image> element gets :focus'ed when I navigate through the page with the Tab button. And it has the ugly focus frame around:
:focus { /* user agent stylesheet */
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}

It's Chrome 129.
I'm a bit surprised, because I supposed that vector elements within an svg shouldn't be focusable at all.
Here are the styles:

Why the element can be :focus'ed at all and how to prevent it from behaving so?
UPD
Accessibility tab says it's focusable:

But I still can't get, how it is possible. What property, style or event handler can make it focusable? BTW, it has an assigned Bootstrap tooltip.
UPD2 This is the result of applying Bootstrap tooltip:
$('.cloudHolder svg .entry').tooltip();

Now I'm investigation what exactly .tooltip(); does to make the element focusable.

I agree, that is intuitively unexpected. Did you try adding tabindex="-1" to the svg or the image element?

Hello @Noleli, thank you! It already has tabIndex="-1" as far as I see in the Properties tab.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/interact.html#Focus

@RobertLongson As I've found, this was affected by setting focusin/focusout event handlers. After removing them the element stops being tabbable.

That were focusin/focusout event handlers. If they are set, Chrome deduces the element is tabbable.
In my case, the handlers were set by popper.js 2.x ($('.cloudHolder svg .entry').tooltip();).

To prevent the focus outline from appearing around your <image> element inside the <svg> when navigating with the Tab button, you can simply remove the default focus outline using CSS.
Add the following styles to target the <image> element within the <svg> and remove the focus outline:
svg image:focus {
    outline: none;
}

If you'd prefer to completely prevent the <image> element from being focusable, you can remove it from the tab navigation by setting the tabindex to -1:
<svg>
    <image tabindex="-1" href="image.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>

This ensures that the <image> element is not focusable, and the focus outline won't appear while tabbing through the page.

Hello Sajd Iqbal, in the Properties tab I see the element already has tabIndex="-1". Removing outline is not an option as it “steals” user clicks on Tab.

Why SVG  is Focusable?
As for me, for Accessibility: for assistive technologies like screen readers. Also Elements with an inherent interactive behavior or elements that can display external resources, like , might be implicitly focusable. Chrome, especially, may add this behavior to improve accessibility for interactive SVG content.
How to Prevent the  Element from Being Focusable mix of these items
I hope will help you

try to set tabindex="-1" at image component
try property: focusable="false"
try css like this:  svg image {  pointer-events: none;}


A screen reader user can access content that normally wouldn’t be tabbable (like paragraphs, headings, and elements with role="img") without making it explicitly tabbable. For example, I wouldn’t recommend adding tabindex="0" to improve accessibility. Only interactive elements should be focusable.

This is a part of a sophisticated 3D animation, so I don't see any point in screen reader support here and would like to disable it completely. tabIndex is already set to "-1". I added focusable="false", but DevTools shows that a computed property named Focusable is still true. And I need mouse events since I have a tooltip, assigned to every <image>.

To prevent the <image> element within an <svg> from receiving focus and displaying the focus outline when navigating through the page with the Tab button, you can add the tabindex="-1" attribute to the <image> element. This will remove it from the tab order and prevent it from being focused.
Here’s an example of how to implement this:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image tabindex="-1" href="image-source.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>

This will ensure that the <image> element inside the <svg> doesn't get focus when you use the Tab key to navigate through the page, avoiding the focus outline (focus ring).
If you want to keep the focus ring for other elements but remove it specifically for this image, you can also apply a CSS rule:
svg image:focus {
  outline: none;
}

This will remove the outline from the <image> when it gets focused without affecting other focusable elements.
